# Firebase database retrieve datas

Tags: java, android

Hi guys im very new with app development ,any ideas how im i able to store my Latitude and Longitude of my users positions with its names and plot in my google maps?

I used this code below and it is working fine it plot the multiple marker as expected , my problem is ,i have my datas from firebase data base please see images[image]

2 users with positions :

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();
    private ArrayList<LatLng> latlngs = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> Names = new ArrayList<>();







    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);




        latlngs.add(new LatLng(12.334343, 33.43434)); //some latitude and logitude value
        latlngs.add(new LatLng(10.334343, 32.43434)); //some latitude and logitude value
        Names.add("Name 1"); //some latitude and logitude value
        Names.add("Name 2"); //some latitude and logitude value







}


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
      //  LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
       // mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
      //  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));


        for (LatLng point : latlngs) {
            options.position(point);
            options.title(String.valueOf(Names));
            options.snippet("someDesc");
            googleMap.addMarker(options);
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: Then what is your question? And have you tried anything with Firebase? I don't see anything regarding firebase in your code

Comment: Yes sir my question is how im i able to retrive my users postions and plot to maps.

Comment: Do you want to store data or retrieve data from firebase databae?

Comment: @AiexaAlexander, Have you configured your project with firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you get data from firbase database and store it in list you want to publish marker on map

you can use this Method

```
public ArrayList<MarkerOptions> publishMarker(GoogleMap googleMap, int recourceMarker) {
    ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markerOption = new ArrayList<>();
    for (LatLng point : latlngs) {
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(point);

  markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(recourceMarker));
        markerOption.add(markerOptions);
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions).setTag(point);
        googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    }
    return markerOption;
}
```

then call method in on mapReady Method

```
ArrayList<MarkerOptions> markerOptions=publishMarker(mMap, R.drawable.map_marker);
 if (markerOptions!=null&&markerOptions.size() > 0)this.mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(markerOptions.get(0).getPosition(), 15));
```

Comment: Hi @ Yousef what is "resultSalonPresnterImp" means? it is showing cannot resolve.

Answer (score 2):

The code below is used to fetch data from firebease:

```
       FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

       DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Positions");

       myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

               for (DataSnapshot chidSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                   System.out.println("id",""+ chidSnap.getKey()); //displays the key for the node
                   System.out.println("Latit",""+ chidSnap.child("Latitude").getValue());  
                   System.out.println.v("Longitude",""+ chidSnap.child("Longitude").getValue());   //gives the value for given keyname
               }

           }

           @Override
           public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

           }
       });
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Thivya now im able to retrieve my datas and i stored it into my arraylist ,but no markers ploted in my maps , any ideas?

Comment: i stored it this way ``` String Lat = String.valueOf(chidSnap.child("Latitude").getValue());
                    String Lon = String.valueOf(chidSnap.child("Longitude").getValue());
                    double latitude= Double.parseDouble(Lat);
                    double longitude= Double.parseDouble(Lon);
                    latlngs.add(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)); //some latitude and logitude value
```

Comment: Change the following onMapReady method ```for (LatLng point : latlngs) {
            googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Marker in Location"));
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(point));
        }```

Comment: same no markers plotted, my maps are showing but no positions added. I'm Confused.

Comment: Try for one point and see if it works under that method and also you have declared several google map objects, just keep one, ``` 
  LatLng sydney =latlangs.get(0);
      googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
      googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));```

Comment: I'm Getting an error : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Comment: yes datas are ok , /System.out: Lex B05
/System.out: 7.1907067
/System.out: amanda
/System.out: 10.0
/System.out: 122.23

Comment: my list showing  : [lat/lng: (7.1907067,125.45534), lat/lng: (10.0,122.23)] i think it's ok, but it is not plotting in my map.

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0  occurs when there is no data inside your list, try checking if the variable name of the list you are calling is correct.

Comment: Your correct @Thivya my list is empty ,but why is that? mylist is empy           
 when in ```  public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) ```                     
 but when fetching from firebase database mylist is not emplt. how to solve this??

Comment: declare the list globally outside the methods and populate it inside the firebase method and then access it on onMapReady method @AiexaAlexander